# Selecting from multiple shape objects and inserting into Word vba

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have multiple company logos on a worksheet that I am trying to select and insert into a Word doc that I am generating as the Workbook is shared and I do not want to reference a drive or centralized location (which I have commented out below and that works). I am at a loss as to how to reference the pic as a string? to replace the file location with the pic/shape that is in the workbook. Any ideas?

```
Dim CompanyLogo As String
Dim Pic As Shape
Dim shp As Object

On Error GoTo ERRHANDLER
INSHEADERLOGO = True


'Select from multiple logos based on user selection
'CompanyLogo = "C:\Users\Me\Dropbox\Pics\My Logo.jpg"
TWB.Activate
IWS.Activate
For Each Pic In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If Pic.Type = msoPicture Then
        If Pic.Name = WD.PicName Then
            Debug.Print Pic.ID
            Debug.Print Pic.Name ' neither worked
            CompanyLogo = Pic.Name
            Set shp = DOC.sections.item(1).headers(1).Shapes.AddPicture(CompanyLogo)
        End If
    End If
Next Pic
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by referencing the pic as a string but here is what I just tried and it gave me all the information you are looking for. Hopefully this will help:

```
Sub PicThing()

    Dim oPic As Shape
    Dim oWS As Worksheet: Set oWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    For Each oPic In oWS.Shapes
        MsgBox "Type: " & oPic.Type & vbCrLf & "Name: " & oPic.Name & vbCrLf & "ID: " & oPic.ID
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Zac. What I am after is how to take the picture that is in the Excel worksheet and insert it into the header of a Word Document that I am  creating. I can get it to work if I reference the picture from my hard drive but I am at a loss of how to reference the picture from the excel sheet since there is no file path that I am aware of (hence the string). I guess to rephrase my question. How do I select the picture/shape in Excel and then add it to the header in Word?